# Make a submit form that uses its input to determine a link

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I want to make a form that upon submitting, opens a html file that uses the users submission at the end of the url in the same tab.

Ex. Submit=link1, Opens code.html/link1 (same window)

As of now, putting, "_self" after window.open("code.html/" + s... just makes the url have a question mark at the end, which I'm told it is because of the GET method.

```
(Javascript)
<script>
var s = document.getElementById("submit").value;
function doFunction(){window.open("code.html/" + s);}
</script>

(HTML)
<form onsubmit="doFunction()">
  <input id="submit" type="text" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can try this:

```
<form onSubmit="return doFunction();" target="_self">
 <input id="text-value" type="text" >
 <input type ="submit">
</form>
```

I also added `submit` button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function doFunction(){
   var s = document.getElementById("text-value").value;
   var url = "code.html/" + s;
   var win = window.open(url, '_self');
   return false;
}
</script>
```